# Kendo UI: Update one columns data on changing value in another column

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

**Scenario**
I am having a grid of product details which on Edit opens up a pop-up comprising of that record details. All fields are readonly except the quantity field. Hence, when I increase or decrease the quantity the price column should reflected based on the value. 
So if quantity of 1 is 10 then when I increase the quantity to 2 it should be reflected to 20.

**Questions**
1) I've studied the editor method a bit, I'll have to use the same method on the quantity column right??

2) How shall I grab the value of the price column and update its value? are there any built in methods like the editor?? How shall I go about??

Following is the JS fiddle which I have prepared. http://jsbin.com/ugeref/3/edit

Thanks!!

-
Hardik

Comment: Try googling for _calculated value_ I this you will find relevant examples.

Comment: Hi Ona, Great to see your comment..have come across to your site and your answers..they give the best solution..Thank you so much for the response...is it the aggregate function you're talking about? well..I'll just google it out... could you pls suggest me any links or materials which i should go through for learning kendo ui?

Comment: Hi Ona, after googling.. I couldn't find relevant links to my solution...However, I was getting telerik links for RadControls eg. http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/change-values-in-radgrid-field-according-to-changes-in-another-field.aspx but that is not what I need... Thanks..

Comment: Did you find [this](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/framework/data-source/create-calculated-value-for-grid.aspx) or [this](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/framework/mvvm/computed-value-based-on-another-computed-value.aspx)

Comment: Nope I didn't find them...So according to the first one,  I need to write another function called CalculatePrice and call it from the editor function of quantity column right?..and then how shall I set the value? Actually I am new to this.. and if you'll check my JSBin example, its actually a pop-up which opens... so it would be great if you would explain me the steps which I need to follow to get to the solution... I'll google those steps and do RnD accordingly... Thanks for the links..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your `DataSource` as:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data  : data,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id    : "Id",
            fields: {
                productName: { editable: false},
                quantity   : { editable: true, type : "number" },
                price      : { editable: false, type : "number" },
                total      : { editable: false, type : "number" }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Where you should add a `total` field that is `quantity` times `price`. 
**NOTE**: In addition, I've defined the type of the different fields to let KendoUI know that are number and generate the correct widgets.

Then, define the `grid` as:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    pageable  : true,
    height    : 400,
    toolbar   : ["create"],
    columns   : [
        { field: "productName", title: "Product Name" },
        { field: "quantity", title: "Quantity", format: "{0:c}"},
        { field: "total", title: "Total", template: "#= quantity * price #", width: "150px" },
        { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;" }
    ],
    editable  : "popup"
});
```

Where I added a `Total` column that uses a template that is the result of `quantity * price`.

Each time that you update `quantity`, `total` will get `updated`.

See you code modified in [here](http://jsbin.com/ugeref/5)

Comment: Hi Ona, Thank you so much for the valuable response!! However the Fiddle works fine...but what if I just had one column? and I had to change the value on the fly? I mean rather than adding a Total column(It does make sense to add the Total Column)..How would I have to go about?

Comment: Do you mean that `price` is `quantity` multiplied by a constant? which is the value of the constant, `10`? Please let me know and I'll update the example.

Comment: Ummmm...No...Your edits were enough for me to fix :) Thanks Ona!! :)

Comment: Hi Ona, I am having a query regarding a similar scenario but in this case, the quantity column is a textbox or autocomplete by default.. [link]http://jsbin.com/ugeref/10/edit when I change the quantity, the Total column should be updated automatically...How shall I refresh the Total column on change in the quantity column? is there any built in method? the formulae is same price * quantity = total ...

Comment: Sorry, why a number (`quantity`) is a textbox and not a `NumericTextBox`? Why did you define an `input` as template (that breaks the fact that the grid is `observable`? Not sure what you are trying to get but seems that is not the easiest approach

Comment: yea...that's not a problem, I can also keep it as a numeric text box, that's totally fine with me... It's just for a particular screen that I've kept the textbox template for a particular column..so when I change it, it should calculate the total for that particular row and after which I click a Done button which would close the window...

Comment: Is there any other approach which I should follow in order to achieve the same?