# How to bind a variable in a grid to another variable in another column in the same grid?

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Grid where i get fees objects that contains : Fees- Taxes - and Fees After Taxes.
Fees after taxes were calculated in the callled from the object ( in the object's class).
i am adding taxes to the fees caclulations, i want when i edit the taxes it automatically edit (fees after taxes) and also updates the total fees after taxes in the footer.

```
function onTaxesChange(e) {
    var TaxesObject = e.sender;
    if (TaxesObject != null) {
        var grid = $("#InvoiceProgressNotesGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        var container = $(TaxesObject.wrapper).parent().parent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just make you total fees calculated like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019940/kendo-ui-update-one-columns-data-on-changing-value-in-another-column).

Comment: but this won't update the object in the backend!

Comment: I want when editing the taxes columns the other column is updated without having a pop-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var item = $("#InvoiceProgressNotesGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));
var progreeNoteId = item.Id;
var Fees = item.Fees;
var Taxes = item.Taxes;
var FeesAfterTaxes = (Fees * Taxes / 100) + Fees;
item["FeesAfterTaxes"] = FeesAfterTaxes;
```

this will update all objects in the selected item in the grid